# How can I format timestamps with embedded `T` character?

Tags: php, xsd, datetime-format, iso8601

I need to format a timestamp in ISO 8601 format (e.g. `2001-10-26T21:32:52`).  When I use the `date()` function in PHP, it replaces `T` with the Timezone (as it is supposed to do).

The command I'm using is:

```
$time = date("y-m-dTH:i:s", time());
```

This produces: `10-02-13EST10:21:03`

How do I get it to insert an actual `T` and not replace with `EST`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your format shoule be : "c"

```
$time = date("c", time());
```

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
Format Descriptions                        Example
c      ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)   2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
```

Comment: If you are using `DateTime`, then `$date->format(DateTime::ATOM)` is what you want.

Comment: Also, you can just use `date("c")`, as `date()` will default to `time()`, if the second arg isn't provided.

Comment: "Atom" format is now depricated (since php 7.2 I think) but solution with escaping T @Matteo suggested works fine.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to insert a character which should not be interpreted, precede it with a backslash:

```
$time = date("y-m-d\TH:i:s", time());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could format the date and time parts seperately, then concatenate the two parts with `"T"`:

```
<?php
 $time = time(); 
 $time = date( "y-m-d",$time )."T".date( "H:i:s", $time );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_ATOM` is provided for this format:

```
$theStart_date = date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime($start_date));
```

Output:

```
2013-04-10T09:10:30-04:00
```